# SQL*Plus fail instead of prompting for substitution variable

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Imagine a file `test.sql` with the following content

```sql
SELECT '&myvar' AS greeting FROM dual;
```

When we run that file in `sqlplus`. We will be prompted for the value of the variable `&myvar` since it's not defined, and that is normally a good thing. But when running automated tasks with non-interactive scripts, this can be a problem.

Is there any way for `sqlplus` to error out when trying to access an undefined variable instead of prompting for it?

This is how the script gets run

```bash
cat test.sql | sqlplus localhost@ORCL
```

Comment: What good will it do for you if the automated task fails? Don't you want to _supply_ the value instead?

Comment: The value will be supplied by other part of the automation which is in charge of defining the variables and it's there it needs to be fixed if it fails. Right now all I need is for sqlplus to fail hopefully setting `$?` to a non-zero value. So it can actually be detected as an scripting error and fixed in the right place.

Comment: from [SQL*Plus User's Guide and Reference 21c, 6.3.1 Where and How to Use Substitution Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqpug/using-substitution-variables-sqlplus.html#GUID-DD1BE849-0B66-4F99-83D0-F3B9F5A0D361) "SQL*Plus reads your response from the keyboard or standard input." So I think there is no direct way to avoid reading from input and exit with error. Maybe there are some workarounds 
to cope with this problem

Comment: As is often the case, it is much better to explain what actual real-life problem you are trying to solve rather than presenting hypothetical or incomplete use cases. In your case: what do you use the variable for ? There is probably a cleaner way to do what you need to do without using variables or using them differently.

Comment: @miracle173 Thanks, I think you are right. I was hoping there some magic `SET ASK_FOR_VARIABLES OFF` I had missed from the docs, but I guess I was hoping too much.

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind I appreciate your eagerness to help, but I was not really looking for alternative solutions. I was looking for a specific answer to a very specific question. If the answer is "can't be done", well so be it. Now I can find other ways to fix it knowing I tried to do it the best way first.

Comment: What OS are you using? You may be able to pipe something like a `CTRL+C` to the sqlplus process so that whenever it stops to prompt the user for input it receives the `CTRL+C` and terminates.

Comment: @AndrewSayer Using Linux. The way it currently works is the system pipes the file to `sqlplus` via it's `stdin`, so when it tries to read the variable what it gets is an end of file, `CTRL+D`. And that does not stop `sqlplus` from going on with the variable undefined and well the result of that is not good at all. So by the time `sqlplus` asks for the variable, the data has already been sent.